# Is there a function to join 2 datasets on multiple column where one of the columns is an inexact numerical match?

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr

I am trying to join 2 datasets together via multiple columns and one of the columns is an inexact numerical match.  The other columns match perfectly because the data are essentially the same but from differences sources.  The numerical mismatch in the final column is time based and the mismatch appears to be that the first dataset has recorded timestamps approximately 1 to 4 seconds before the second dataset.

The 1st dataset has approximately 100 more observations than the second and I am trying to extract information from the first to add to the second.  The reason for this is the first dataset with the extra information that I need only has millesecond granularity, whereas the second dataset without the required information has nanosecond granularity.

```
    sample1:
    1   date        time   seconds  2   3    ID1  ID2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      50  200   2    3
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      51  40    2    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  30    5    2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  100   6    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      51  60    1    6

    sample2:
    1   date        time   seconds  2   3  
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      50  200
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      51  40
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  30
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   26      50  100
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   26      51  60
```

The first thing I did was make sure that each dataset had the same column headers and the information contained in the columns that I am trying to match are of the same class and are in the same format.

For the timestamp, I separated this column in both datasets so there is now 1 column each for "date", "time" (hours:minutes:seconds), with fourth column showing the milleseconds / nanoseconds respectively.  Note: I am trying to match the "date" column along with other columns that have information that mostly matches and isn't because I can see that most of matches.  The **time** column is the one that is causing problems.  I then tried using `dplyr` to `mutate` the seconds to a separate column.  When I try to do an `inner_join` with `date`, `time`, `seconds`, and the other 3 columns I end up with around `1000` less observations than I should.  When I do an `inner_join` with the aforementioned columns except the **seconds** column, I end up with around `2000` more observations than I should.  I suspect this is because `inner_join` is matching multiple time(?).

I have also tried `right_join` and `left_join` to which I have similar issues with the **seconds** column.  A `full_join` literally just adds the datasets together which I expected.

Another thing I tried was the `merge` function.  This gave the same results as the `inner_join` both when I included and excluded the **seconds** columns in the join.

Lastly, I tried `fuzzyjoin` but for some reason this killed the memory in my laptop and crashed it.

A couple of things I haven't tried are: using a `for loop` to try to get the info from the first dataset to the second, because the final datasets that I need to join like have hundreds of millions of observations.  `match` also doesn't appear to work because it only seems to work on 1 column, not the 6 columns that I need matched.

1. This gives 1000 less observations than it should because it's not picking up the inexact mismatch on the seconds:

```r
merged_data <- inner_join(sample1, sample2,
                               by = c('1' = '1','Date'='Date', 'Time'='Time',
                               'seconds'='seconds', '2' ='2', '3'= '3')
                               ) %>% as_tibble()`
```

2. This gives me approx 2000 observations more than I should:

```r
merged_data <- inner_join(sample1, sample2, 
                               by = c('1' = '1','Date'='Date', 
                               'Time'='Time', '2' ='2', '3'= '3')
                               ) %>% as_tibble()
```

3. And doing this shows me the observations that didn't match by putting them below the rows that did match:

```r
merged_data <- inner_join(sample1, sample2, 
                               by = c('1' = '1','Date'='Date', 
                               'Time'='Time', 'seconds'='seconds', 
                               '2' ='2', '3'= '3'), all.x = TRUE
                               ) %>% as_tibble()
```

4. This fuzzyjoin code kills the memory on my laptop and crashes it:

```r
merged_data = fuzzyjoin(sample1, sample2, 
                             by = c('1' = '1','Date'='Date',
                             'Time'='Time', 'seconds'='seconds', 
                             '2' ='2', '3'= '3'), 
                             match_fun = list(`==`, `==`, `==`, `<=`, `==`, `==`)
                             ) %>% as_tibble()
```

Expected results:

```
    merged_data
    1   date        time   seconds  2   3    ID1  ID2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      50  200   2    3
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      51  40    2    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  30    5    2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   26      50  100   6    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   26      51  60    1    6
```

Actual results when seconds are included on the `inner_join` and `merge`:

```
    merged_data
    1   date        time   seconds  2   3    ID1  ID2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      50  200   2    3
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      51  40    2    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  30    5    2
```

Actual results from the merge with `all.x = TRUE`:

```
    merged_data
    1   date        time   seconds  2   3    ID1  ID2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      50  200   2    3
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   24      51  40    2    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  30    5    2
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   26      50  100   6    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   26      51  60    1    6
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      50  100   6    4
    CBA 2015-01-02  10:30   25      51  60    1    6
```

Comment: First thing is you can only join two tables when they have the index variable (or a compound variable - as in your case) unique in _at least one_ of the two tables. Is that so in your dataset? Can you please confirm that by checking uniqueN() for the compound variable? The unique count must match the total rows in one of the two data frames. Joining the two tables on approx value is easy then. We can take a "range" concept. Will explain it once you confirm above.

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra There is not uniqueness in the compound variable that I am trying to join in the main datasets.  If I was to join using the millisecond timestamp then maybe, however, as described above this is not possible.  The best scenario that I can think of is to match each row as they come, however this would be very cumbersome on computing power on the final datasets if I was to try using a for loop.  When you say that you can take a "range" concept, is this possible using `match` or `join`? As long as the `seconds` column is within a range of approx 2 seconds then that is a win.

Comment: Use ```dput``` with timestamp included - fuzziness with the seconds won't work because the minutes won't match all the time as well. Splitting up the time in all these time components isn't super helpful.

Comment: As @Cole noted please use `dput` to dump data. And you don't need to split time in so many components. A clean original data might help us give you a solution faster.

Comment: Ok, so I checked out `dput`...I'm not exactly sure what that is supposed to achieve?  @Cole, I understand the minutes won't exactly match either under certain circumstances in the same way the seconds won't match.  And I also understand that separating the timestamps may not be the best way to go. The question then becomes, how to do you match timestamps within a couple of seconds of each other when all the other columns already match, without using `lappy` or something like that?  @Sanjay, unfortunately I cannot provide a sample of the actual data because they're proprietary data.

Comment: Our point is to provide data as a timestamp. It's fine if it's proprietary but you might as well provide it in timestamp because most solutions would likely convert your output to timestamp.

Comment: @Cole I am not exactly sure what you mean, and also do not understand the point to using `dput`.  Could you please explain further?  I am not a very experienced R user.

Comment: The preference is to copy and paste the output from the ```dput```. If that is not an option the request is to make your example dataset be in POSIXct instead of split into all of the sub components of time.